# Dovecot Mailbox on Dropbox

Tags: dovecot

I have setup a local Dovecot server on my system and I want to store any emails I send to it in a dropbox folder. I have the following `mail_location` setting:

```
mail_location = "Absolute path to my dropbox folder"
```

I can connect to the server just fine and it also allows me to store emails on it. However, when I check the dropbox directory, it is empty. Where are my emails going?

**UPDATE:**
Ok I've managed to figure out that the path specified in `mail_location` is being created under `base_dir`. But that is not the behaviour I want. I want the mailboxes to be stored in the path I've specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem by creating a symlink to my Dropbox folder under `base_dir`.